# Qt: Paintevent and parent child relation?

Tags: qt

If I have paprent widget A, then I have a children widget B of A. B is embedded inside A.

If I trigger paintEvent of A , will B's paint event be triggered?
If I trigger paintEvent of B , will A's paint event be triggered?

If it is depended on some other properties, what are the properties? Transparency?
Is there a general rule so I could know which Widget's paint event will be triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most helpful answer is you should write your `paintEvent` methods not to care. Because the actual answer will depend on the platform you are running on, and as you guessed transparency likely plays a part as well, but whether widgets are native-backed may also matter.

Qt5 always uses double-buffered drawing for all widgets, but it's unspecified at what granularity (windows, all widgets, only native-backed widgets) the buffering actually occurs. If both widgets are opaque, I'd guess only the widget you invalidate will be re-drawn, because the other will be preserved in the backing store. But I wouldn't be totally surprised if invalidating A causes a repaint of B, either.

Since there's so many things beyond your control that can cause a paint event, again the simplest answer would be to ensure your painting code does not care, and trust in the double-buffering mechanism to only call your code when it needs too. (Assuming you're not calling `update()` yourself too much)

Answer (score 2):

If you depend on what circumstances the `paintEvent` can be called in, you're doing it wrong. A `paintEvent` must be **always** callable if the widget is visible. You **must** expect it to be called at any time, no matter what happens to the rest of the system.

Ideally, your implementation of `paintEvent` should not modify the state of the object. I find it helpful to forward the implementation to a `const` helper to make it obvious:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    QPainter painter(this);
    paintEventImpl(event, painter);
  }
  void paintEventImpl(QPaintEvent *, QPainter &) const;
  ...
};
```

Comment: My paintEvent is always callable, the problem is that it is a little bit expensive (drawing many images). So I want to reduce the number of times it is called.

Comment: @Nyaruko Image drawing shouldn't be expensive, it's a striped memory copy iff your images aren't scaled. If you scale the images, it will help to cache them. It should be very fast, if not, your `paintEvent` is somehow broken. Your question is the classical X-Y. You worry about when `paintEvent` is called, but instead you should ask how to make it faster!